# in visual studio C#, how to add a control's code behind automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have used VB.net on a web page and added an asp:button on the front page and in the code behind i can just click on events and the button name in the top drop downs and select click event. Visual studio's will auto create my function/sub for that event.
i am just learning to write everything in C# and i do not see this option to auto create my code.
it has the code of a declaration in the designer.cs file and says to move that line into the code behind of the page. but i need to either remove that or just add the sub to handle the click event.

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnSubmit;
```

1) i do see that if i go into the designer of that page and double click the button i can get it to auto generate the code. BUT is there not a way to do it from the code behind like i do it in vb.net?

2) do i need to move that line of code above from the designer.cs to my code behind file?

Comment: Are you talking about Web Forms? MVC? Razor? Core?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you trying to mix two languages in the code behind of the very same page? What the `@Page Language` directive says?

Comment: @DourHighArch: `System.Web.UI.WebControls` sounds like Web Forms.

Comment: vb.net was a previously used language. This new question is in Web Forms C# (only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves me correctly, you can follow the steps below to produce the same result in a c# web forms application:

1. Select the UI element on either a web form (.aspx) or a User Control (.ascx).
2. Select the Object Explorer or Properties Viewer (the higlighted control should be selected).
3. Select the events tab (lighning bolt).
4. Double click on the event that you want to have the server side event handler auto generated for.